# Split Dataframe into list of one-row Dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to split a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = letters[1:4])

  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
```

into a list of one-row dataframes

```
list(
    data.frame(a = 1, b = letters[1])
    , data.frame(a = 2, b = letters[2])
    , data.frame(a = 3, b = letters[3])
    , data.frame(a = 4, b = letters[4])
)

[[1]]
  a b
1 1 a

[[2]]
  a b
1 2 b

[[3]]
  a b
1 3 c

[[4]]
  a b
1 4 d
```

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Perhaps `unname(split(df, 1:nrow(df)))`

Comment: @markus can you please make this an answer? I really like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to use the `split()` command built into R

```
split( df, 1:length( df$a ) )
```

It should be robust enough to handle duplicates in `df$a`.

Comment: It is robust in that regard. A little better would be `split(df, 1:nrow(df))`

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 group_split(rowid, keep = FALSE) 

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <fct>
1     1 a    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <fct>
1     2 b    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <fct>
1     3 c    

[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <fct>
1     4 d
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(rowid = 1:n()) %>%
 group_split(rowid, keep = FALSE)
```

Or a shortened version (provided by @arg0naut91):

```
group_split(df, row_number(), keep = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be with `asplit`

```
lapply(asplit(df, 1), as.data.frame.list)
#[[1]]
#  a b
#1 1 a

#[[2]]
#  a b
#1 2 b

#[[3]]
#  a b
#1 3 c

#[[4]]
#  a b
#1 4 d
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap(df, tibble)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a b    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     1 a    

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a b    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     2 b    

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a b    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     3 c    

#[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a b    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     4 d
```

Comment: Why `asplit` and not `split(df, df$a) `?